# Firebase database output alphabetical sort issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase query that finds all the systems in my database (database called Faults) and puts them in a table. The trouble is the table that's produced is in the order in which I added the items to the database, and not in alphabetical order as I would like. Any idea what I have missed (messed up!)?

```
    var theroot = firebase.database().ref("Faults/");
    theroot.orderByChild("system").on("value", Show_system_table, errData);

    function Show_system_table(data) {

        var raw_data = data.val();
        var results_array = Object.values(raw_data);

        for (i = 0; i < results_array.length; i++) {

            var single_item = results_array[i]; 
            var result_name = single_item.system; 
            var markup = "<tr> <td>" + result_name + "</td> </tr>";
            $("#system_tbl").append(markup);
        }
    }

    function errData() {
        console.log("Error issues");
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Peter

PS - I know I should put the var's outside the loop (I will later, promise!)

Comment: `orderByValue` instead of `orderByChild` doesn't help?
From - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data

Comment: Hello - It may be me, but this resulted in this error message. Uncaught Error: Query.orderByValue failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects none.

Comment: @PeterW do not add anything inside `orderByValue()`.. does not accept arguments..

Comment: Thanks Peter - This did not result in the correct (desired) order. This is the code with the suggested change  const theroot = firebase.database().ref();
        theroot.child('Faults').orderByValue().on("value", Show_system_table, errData);  - The result was the same as before. The solution below Frank gave has worked for me, but I appreciate both of your inputs in an attempt to help. regards Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute a query on the Firebase Database it returns three pieces of information for each child:

1. Its value.
2. Its key.
3. Its relative order against other child nodes.

When you call `data.val()` you're converting the result to a regular JSON object, which unfortunately only has place for the first two of these. So the order of the items is lost at this point.

To maintain the order, use the built-in `Snapshot.forEach` method:

```
function Show_system_table(data) {
    data.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        var single_item = snapshot.val(); 
        var result_name = single_item.system; 
        var markup = "<tr> <td>" + result_name + "</td> </tr>";
        $("#system_tbl").append(markup);
    });
}
```

Comment: Frank - Massive thanks for your fast and excellent help, it worked perfectly. There are three small issues anyone who uses this code above should be aware of.  1/ in line three a typo, its snapshot, not snapshow. 2/ The .val needs () adding. and finally 3/ The second to last line needs ); at the end to close the function. Small things,easily fixed and should not to detract from your answer. Thanks again, I really appreciate it. Peter

Comment: Ouch... that's a lot of typos in such a small fragment. Thanks for catching them and still getting what I meant Peter! I fixed the snippet.